# Как создать меню регистрации для Телеграмм бота на Java?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет! Учусь писать телеграмм ботов. Пытаюсь реализовать бота знакомств, но есть одна задачка, которую не могу решить. Суть в том что при запуске бота высвечивается приветственное сообщение и кнопка "Регистрация", при "регистрации" начинается опрос, составление анкеты (пока что бот-пустышка). Вот фрагмент кода бота:

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        if(message != null && message.hasText()) {
            String chat_id = String.valueOf(message.getChatId());
            String inMsg = message.getText();
            User user = new User();
            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
            sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(message.getChatId()));
            sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);

            try {
                sendMessage.setText(getMessage(message, user));
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getMessage(Message message, User user) {
        String inMsg = message.getText();
        String chat_id = String.valueOf(message.getChatId());
        user.chat_id = chat_id;
        ArrayList<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
        KeyboardRow keyboardRow = new KeyboardRow();

        keyboardMarkup.setSelective(false);
        keyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);



        if (inMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("/start")) {
            keyboard.clear();
            keyboardRow.clear();
            keyboardRow.add("Регистрация");
            keyboard.add(keyboardRow);
            keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            return "Здесь ты сможешь найти себе вторую половинку или просто познакомиться с новыми людьми!\n" +
                    "Нажми \"Регистрация\", чтобы создать анкету";
        }

        if (inMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Регистрация")) {
            keyboard.clear();
            keyboardRow.clear();
            keyboardRow.add("Я парень");
            keyboardRow.add("Я девушка");
            keyboard.add(keyboardRow);
            keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            return "Отлично. Начнем.\nКто ты?";
        }

        if (inMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Я парень") || inMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Я девушка")) {
            if (inMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Я парень"))
                user.gender = "Male";
            if (inMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Я девушка"))
                user.gender = "Female";
            keyboard.clear();
            keyboardRow.clear();
            keyboardRow.add("Парня");
            keyboardRow.add("Девушку");
            keyboardRow.add("Все равно");
            keyboard.add(keyboardRow);
            keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            return "Кого ищешь?";
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Но такая реализация неправильная, хочу раскидать все в меню, т.е. Приветствие-(Реакция на любое сообщение, в том числе кнопка "Регистрация")->Регистрация-(После заполнение анкеты, т.е как в фрагменте кода, вопрос-ответ и последующее заполнение в БД)->Знакомства(часть где свои кнопки и функционал, поиск анкет, просмотр своей, редактирование своей). Как можно реализовать такое "Меню" для бота? Работаю в InelliJ IDEA на языке Java с библиотекой TelegramBots.

Comment: А какая у вас операционная система?

Comment: @Alexandr Windows

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ

Comment: @Alexandr лол данные собираете?